# Filtering 2 tables that are in relations (1:n)

Tags: qgis-3

I work with two tables which are in relations from 1 to n (one to many) : An individual owns several goods.
My individuals are in the main form and their assets are displayed as a table in the sub form.
I want to map the doctors who own a pet for example.
How do I do the filtering?
For now, I make a query on each table and then I join them by an attribute join. It works well.
Is this the right way ?
Can we do this more straightforward?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use a virtual layer to store your join and run your queries with SQL.
Have a look at: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html?highlight=virtual%20layers#creating-virtual-layers
or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AE6WALlNicw (QGIS - Buffer layer - Add as Virtual Layer from PostGIS using SQL Statements) Here you can see how virtual layers are applied.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Can you suggest me a tutorial ressource ?

Comment: You are welcome, i have edited my original answer.

Comment: thnak you but i dont kwon how to join the 2 table in sql `select * from people, goods where "goods category" ="pets" ` retourn me many john and janes...

Comment: I don't know your data structure but a classic left join would look like: 
SELECT
 id,
 people,
 goods,
 
FROM
 people
Left JOIN goods
    ON goods.id = people.id
WHERE goods = 'pets' 

Please note to put the correct table names in front of the column names if they are ambiguous.